# declaring parameters when executing stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I've created a test stored procedure that pull selected records from a view.  I use Sql Server Management Studio 2012.  The code I used to create it is:

```
create procedure [dbo].[andytest]
@CpnyID char(3)
, @FiscYr char(4)
, @LedgerID char(10)
, @Acct char(10)
as select * From dbo.view_Normal_AcctHist_Leads_AllEntities
where CpnyID in(@CpnyID)
and FiscYr in(@FiscYr)
and LedgerID in(@LedgerID)
and Acct in(@Acct)
```

When executing I use:

```
exec andytest
   @CpnyID= '131'
  ,@FiscYr='2014'
  ,@LedgerID='Actual'
  ,@Acct='637100'
```

I've noticed when I script the procedure as an 'Execute', the code that comes is:

```
DECLARE @CpnyID char(3)
DECLARE @FiscYr char(4)
DECLARE @LedgerID char(10)
DECLARE @Acct char(10)

-- TODO: Set parameter values here.
set @CpnyID= '131'
set @FiscYr='2014'
set @LedgerID='Actual'
set @Acct='637100'

EXECUTE [dbo].[andytest] 
   @CpnyID
  ,@FiscYr
  ,@LedgerID
  ,@Acct
```

My question is why would the variables that were defined when the procedure was created need to be re-declared when executing and does it matter which method I should use in this particular case?

Sincerely,
Andy

Comment: When using the Script As Execute it will generate the parameters for you. Typically when you call a stored procedure you pass it parameters, not hard coded values. Also, be careful in your procedure code. You are using IN instead of =. I am concerned you think you can pass a delimited list as the value of a parameter and have your procedure return the list. Parameters don't work like that.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers and comments.  they were all helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you execute like this ...

```
DECLARE @CpnyID char(3)
DECLARE @FiscYr char(4)
DECLARE @LedgerID char(10)
DECLARE @Acct char(10)

-- TODO: Set parameter values here.
set @CpnyID   = '131'
set @FiscYr   = '2014'
set @LedgerID = 'Actual'
set @Acct     = '637100'

EXECUTE [dbo].[andytest]   @CpnyID   = @CpnyID
                          ,@FiscYr   = @FiscYr
                          ,@LedgerID = @LedgerID
                          ,@Acct     = @Acct
```

OR you pass values directly to procedure Variables like this......

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[andytest]   @CpnyID   = '131'
                          ,@FiscYr   = '2014'
                          ,@LedgerID = 'Actual'
                          ,@Acct     = '637100'
```

It doesnt make any difference, The only thing is variable are used when you are getting these values from another procedure or API or some sort of other application.

So you declare variable and populate them from values being passed from another source and just pass them to this procedure. Otherwise functionality wise there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

The variables are not being re-declared, ie, the stored procedure does not require this.  The query window requires you declare the vars before assigning them values, again, in this query window.  You could replace the vars with the actual values.

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[andytest]
        @CpnyID = N'2',
        @FiscYr = N'2',
        @LedgerID = N'3',
        @Acct = N'4'
```